# Seaborn - categorical variables in x-y axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot a swarmplot using categorical variables in the X-Y axis. 
I used melt to make a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Day Condition Category value
4   WT        cat1     96.0  
4   WT        cat1     74.0
7   WT        cat1     48.0
7   WT        cat1     79.0
10  WT        cat1     29.0
10  WT        cat1     49.0
4   WT        cat2     50.0
4   WT        cat2     57.0
4   WT        cat2     57.0
7   WT        cat2     75.0
7   WT        cat2     49.0
10  WT        cat2     51.0
10  WT        cat2     71.0
4   WT        cat3     19.0
4   WT        cat3     14.0
7   WT        cat3     54.0
7   WT        cat3     30.0
...
```

I would like to get a swarmplot showing the 'Category' in the y-axis and the 'Day' in the x-axis. In addition, the number of observations (Column 'value') should correspond to dots in every category per day.

Any help is highly appreciated,

Comment: Did you try something? Could you please share your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
sns.swarmplot(x='Day', y='value', hue='Category', data=df)
```

Output:

[image]